# Create wifi network in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, 17.10

How do I create a new wifi network in Ubuntu 17.10? In older versions there is an **Edit connections** option in the menu bar where you can create a new wifi network. But in Ubuntu 17.10 I didn't find this option.

Without this **create new wifi** option I don't know how to share my internet using a wireless hotspot.

The important thing is I am trying to share a **wired** connection 
via hotspot, not a wireless connection from hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on *Activities*, search for *Settings* and open it.
2. Go to **Wi-Fi** section.
3. Click on the vertical ellipsis (three vertical dots) or something similar at the top right to open a pop-up dialogue. You should find a "*Turn On Wi-Fi Hotspot*" option there:
   [image]

If you're unable to transmit data even after turning on hotspot, try this: [Wi-fi hotspot doesn't transmit data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973784/wi-fi-hotspot-doesnt-transmit-data)

Comment: I've done that,but I cannot find any wifi network in my android phone.Moreover the hotspot turns off itself after some time.

Comment: No I am trying to share my wired connection via hotspot

Comment: @GowthamChowdary See the last part of my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The option to create a WiFi hotspot in 17.10 has moved just slightly.  It is now in the menu to the right of the slider turning wifi on and off...

[image]