# Wi-fi hotspot doesn't transmit data

Tags: 17.10, hot-spot

Wi-fi hot-spot doesn't transmit data after startup or just doesn't work properly, however it is possible to connect to it. After turning it off and on it changes it's network name and there is no possibility to change it back at ***Settings*** -> **Wi-Fi**.

Answer (score 1):

To change network name back use `nm-connection-editor`.

To make wi-fi work again run ***Settings*** -> **Wi-Fi** -> **≡** -> **Connect to Hidden Network...** and select appropriate hot-spot connection.